# CKEDITOR event saveSnapshot fires twice before instanceReady

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have an issue with event ordering in CKEDITOR integration (inline mode).

Basically I need to run some custom code when CKEDITOR save a snapshot for the UNDO manager. At the moment I am using event `saveSnapshot`.

As you can see from example below `saveSnapshot` fires twice before `instanceReady`.

I would like to know:

- Why event `saveSnapshot` fires twice? As from documentation it should be triggered only when the editor is about to save an undo snapshot.
- How to fix it? Or an alternative event substitute?

https://jsbin.com/riginoxipe/edit?html,console,output

```
this.ckDisable.call(this);
 this.target = document.getElementById(this.targetId);
 this.target.contentEditable = true;
 this.target.focus();
 this.ckEditor = CKEDITOR.inline(this.target.id);

 this.ckEditor.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
     console.log('instanceReady');
 }.bind(this));

 this.ckEditor.on('change', function(event) {
     console.log('change');
 }.bind(this));

 this.ckEditor.on('afterCommandExec', function(event) {
     console.log('saveSnapshot');
 }.bind(this));

 this.ckEditor.on('saveSnapshot', function(event) {
     console.log('saveSnapshot');
 }.bind(this));
```